# NodeJS require/import module from higher level directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I am using node v9.2.0. Want to load module located in higher level directory.

Here is minimal example: https://github.com/skkap/es6importtest

Suppose I have following dir structure:

```
/common/
   index.mjs
/app/
   app.mjs
   /node_modules/
   package.json
```

`index.mjs` contains some logic and also imports some npm module, like `graphql`.

```
import graphql from 'graphql'

...

export default graphql
```

I want to import `common/index.mjs` module from `app.js`.

```
import common from '../common/'
```

And get the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module graphql

Any ideas where the problem is?

I checked, it also works the same wat with require(): https://github.com/skkap/es6importtest/tree/master/requireTest

P.S. Please do not recommend using npm packages or webpack for that, this question is about the particular problem described above.

Comment: do you export something in `index.mjs`?

Comment: The error comes from index.mjs? or app.mjs?

Comment: @Sag1v Yes, modified answer now

Comment: @IdanDagan `graphql` only imported in `index.mjs`. And when I am changing `graphql` to `graphql123` - error becomes `Error: Cannot find module graphql123'. So error appears in index.mjs

Comment: So you are exporting an empty object from `index.mjs`?

Comment: @Sag1v Is it actually important, error appears before exporting, right? I made minimal test version to show the problem: https://github.com/skkap/es6importtest

Comment: The problem is not related to ES6 imports. Works same way with require(). Example here: https://github.com/skkap/es6importtest/tree/master/requireTest

Comment: Isn't the `package.json` supposed to be at the same level with `app` and `common`?

Comment: @Khang I want to have several apps with their own `package.json`, is it not possible? Where is this restriction described in the documentation?

Comment: If `common` is a separate app, you need to have a `package.json` for it. You can read more about how modules in Node work here https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders

Comment: @Khang nope, `common` is just bunch of shared code, used by other apps.

Comment: then you need to make `common` as a standalone Node module